# Show UIImageView from image url in a table view cell

Tags: multithreading, uiimageview, nsurl

I want to show images in my table view's cells. I have created custom cells for table and every cell has a UIImageView.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"autocompletelistcell";

    Data *data=[datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/image.jpg"]]];
    cell.imageview.image=image;
    cell.name=data.name;

    return cell;
}
```

But it takes long time to load all images (actually only 5 images but different sizes) and doesn't show UITableView until loads all images.

Is it possible to show table and cells before completing loading of images? I guess I need multithreading?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using the [AFNetworking libraries](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and in particular UIImageView+AFNetworking.

Then you can just do something like this and have the images load async...

```
[cell.imageview setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/image.jpg"
                               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```